# Person.gif shown for all posters in threaded view of Discussion Board

Tags: discussion-board, user-profile

I have one farm where all Discussion Board threaded views show the cartoonish Person.gif picture for all users. I know the users posting have pictures in their profile that show in the site collection because they show correctly in the Contact Details Web Part.

Can you suggest troubleshooting steps or propose a solution? I've checked the IIS Log for 404 erorrs. There are none on thumb.jpg or user+photo. I've checked that all three sizes of the thumbnails exist.

People search and My Sites all show the user's photo from their User Profile.

Comment: does this farm have different AAMs?

Comment: Yes. I believe there is more than one mapping. It may be that default is the computername and external is the fqn i use to access it from where I am.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the User Profile to SharePoint Full/Quick Synchronization timer job is running correctly.

Comment: It's running. How do I make sure it's running correctly? Everything else seems to be falling in place but the discussion board.

Answer (score 2):

Try to inspect User Information List.

http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2008/06/25/sharepoints-hidden-user-list-user-information-list.aspx

Properties from User Profile (shown in search result and My Site) are propagated to User Information Lists in sharepoint sites, but mau be overriden.

Comment: Here's a fun one. I went to _catalogs/users/simple.aspx, added a new view with the picture column and the correct picture shows! Thanks for suggesting that. I wouldn't have known how all the fields show now without trying that.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same problem and fixed it.

If you have a "Missing server side dependencies" error in your Central Administration health analyzer then you first need to follow [these instructions](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/63378c77-7d10-44f6-9a7f-787d0927b1b3/#b8a21e8a-6fb1-475e-9b42-5e226fab48fa) 
(I know this looks like it's not related but I promise you, it is!)

Credit goes to John D. Palm for the first part of the solution to this problem.

the second thing you need to do, now that the timer service is running is you need to sync the profiles, or you can just wait an hour and they will sync by themselves.  I like to do things by hand so I know I have the right answer.  The way you do that is go into Central Administration > Monitoring > Job Definitions and then go down to these two jobs and run them now and in this order:

User Profile Service Application - User Profile Change Job
User Profile Service Application - User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization

Once you do that, reload your discussion threads in list view and you will see the profile pictures showing up.  Let your people know that these pictures won't update on the fly.  If they change their profile picture, the old picture will still show in the discussion thread until The sync job runs.  By default the User profile change job is set to run hourly.